# How to Access Parent class variable in Python and Call Parent Method using Child Object

Tags: python, inheritance

I am practicing Python Inheritance. I am not able to access and parent class variable in child class and not able to call parent class using child's object.

```
class carmodel():
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model=model
    def model_name(self):
        print("Car Model is", self.model)
        
class cartype(carmodel):
    def __init__(self, typ):
        super().__init__(self, model)
        self.typ = typ
    def ctyp(self):
        print(self.model, "car type is",self.typ)
car1=cartype("Sports")
car1.ctyp()
car1.model_name("Tesla Plaid")
```

Comment: Please post the full error traceback!

Comment: When using OOP, you should use return instead of print.

Comment: is `super().__init__(self, model)` correct? does it need the `self` parameter?

Comment: @PCM using return in class methods has nothing to do with OOP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?
Few udpates in your code:
function `model_name()` is expected to print the `model_name` assigned to the car, and as `carmodel` is parent of `cartype`, the model info needs to be passed to parent class and store it in `self`. So initialize `cartype` with `type` and `model` and pass this `model` to parent class as done in the code below:

```
class carmodel():
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model=model
    def model_name(self):
        print("Car Model is", self.model)
        
class cartype(carmodel):
    def __init__(self, typ, model):
        super().__init__(model)
        self.typ = typ
    def ctyp(self):
        print(self.model, "car type is",self.typ)
car1=cartype("Sports", "Tesla Plaid")
car1.ctyp()
car1.model_name()
```

Output:

```
Tesla Plaid car type is Sports
Car Model is Tesla Plaid
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Is it mandatory to call model argument in child class both def __init__  and super functions?

Comment: You are creating a child class object, hence it's required, else there's no way parent class will know the model of the car..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reconstruction of your code that you might find useful:-

```
class carmodel():
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model=model
    def model_name(self):
        return f'Model={self.model}'
        
class cartype(carmodel):
    def __init__(self, typ, model):
        super().__init__(model)
        self.typ = typ
    def ctyp(self):
        return f'Model={self.model}, type={self.typ}'

car=cartype("Sports", 'Plaid')
print(car.ctyp())
print(car.model_name())
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But, your code returned below output which is not desriable.
`
Model=Plaid, type=Sports
Model=Plaid
`

Comment: Are you being serious?

Comment: @AnilAnvesh can't you edit the return  statement ?

Comment: @sahasrara62 Yes I can, but I missed the arguments part in child's class. I didn't understand it until now.